# Problem with sending client side data to server side (django)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to send client side data(html5 api for latitude and longitude) to server side. I am not familiar with JS but i found the code for two JS functions for latitude and longtitude:

```
function latitude() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            return document.getElementById('latitude').setAttribute("value", position.coords.latitude);
        }
        );
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
    }
}
function longitude() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            return document.getElementById('longitude').setAttribute("value", position.coords.longitude);
        }
        );
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
    }
}
```

Then I created django form which will receive the data:

```
class CordsForm(forms.Form):
    latitude = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'id': 'latitude', 'type': 'hidden'}))
    longitude = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'id': 'longitude', 'type': 'hidden'}))
```

Also i created view which uses the form:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cords_form = CordsForm(request.POST)
        if cords_form.is_valid():
            latitude = cords_form.cleaned_data['latitude']
            longitude = cords_form.cleaned_data['longitude']
            print(longitude) # only for testing
            print(latitude) # only for testing
    else:
        cords_form = CordsForm()
    return render(request, 'weather/index.html', {'form': cords_form})
```

This is the index page:

```
{% extends 'weather/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" id="geoform" name="geoform">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.latitude }}
    <script>latitude();</script>
    {{ form.longitude }}
    <script>longitude();</script>
</form>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        document.getElementById("geoform").submit();
    });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Every time a user visits the index page, the latitude and longitude is sent automatically via the form, but this code:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        document.getElementById("geoform").submit();
    });
</script>
```

sends the data but it is refreshing the page like i am spamming the F5 button. How can i send the data only once when the index page is visited?

Comment: you should use ajax for this task

Answer (score 0):

you should local storage:

and when you want sent data to server check that and if you don't have that function can sent that

you should use this code in a if statement that check you local storage than run this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        document.getElementById("geoform").submit();
```

like this:

```
var check = localStorage.getItem('posted');
if(check !== 'true'){
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        document.getElementById("geoform").submit();
localStorage.setItem('posted','true')
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: but better way for this problem is ajax

Comment: can you tell me about the ajax, what to search etc, because i dont know js and ajax i  am only familiar with python and django, html, css

Comment: this help you https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp , but my question should work